# Ruby on Rails | Setting Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Are there any other ways to set attributes for models in Rails other than using `attribute=`?

For example, is there something like `set_attribute(name, value)`?

```
user = User.new
user.set_attribute(:name, 'Jack')
user.set_attribute(:surname, 'The Ripper')
user.save

# instead of
user.name = 'Jack'
user.surname = 'The Ripper'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [write_attribute](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Write/write_attribute) method. It should be what you're looking for.

*EDIT*

You can use [update_attributes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attributes) if you want to update many attributes at once.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, lucapette. Is there a similar method which allows to assign several attributes at once? Something like `write_attributes`.

Comment: [update_attributes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes) method is available for immedeately attributes update(with saving) and here is [attributes=](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attributes%3D) also, which just modifying original object without saving

Comment: @Shamaoke As 4pcbr has said if you want to write many attributes at once you can use update_attributes.

Comment: According to ApiDock, `attributes=` is outdated. `update_attributes` doesn't fit well since it saves attributes and also, I think, its purpose still not to *set* but to *update*.

Comment: @Shamaoke I see. So you just want to set a lot of attributes a time. Whitout persisting them?

Comment: @lucapette. That's right. Look at the [gist](https://gist.github.com/1798362). There I tried to explain what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

looking to the AR source we can find

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb, line 208
def update_attributes(attributes, options = {})
  # The following transaction covers any possible database side-effects of the
  # attributes assignment. For example, setting the IDs of a child collection.
  with_transaction_returning_status do
    self.assign_attributes(attributes, options)
    save
  end
end
```

so you can use `assign_attributes(attributes, options)` to set attributes without saving

Also if you want to set attribute by name without calling a method directly you can use
`user.send(:name=, 'Jack')` instead of `user.set_attribute(:name, 'Jack')`